# How to access the value of a std::atomic<int> as non-atomic

Tags: c++, atomic, stdatomic

I have an atomic variable in my program of type `atomic<int>`. At some places I don't need to access the value in it atomically, as I just check if its 0 or not. In other words, at those instances I want to avoid the overhead of bus locking etc. that happens when there is atomic access.

How can I access the atomic variable non-atomically. Is typecasting it with (int) enough, like as follows? If not, which I think, how can I do this?

```
atomic<int> atm;
int x;
........
x = (int)atm; // Would this be a non-atomic access, no bus locking et all?
```

Comment: Checking if it's zero or not has nothing to do with whether or not it needs to be atomic.

Comment: Only at some instances I do need to check for zero, not all the time.

Comment: I still don't see the connection: the only deciding factor for using an atomic value is whether or not you need it to avoid data races. So the only time you should say "I don't need to read it atomically" is because you're positive no other threads will access it.

Comment: GMan sometimes yes, sometimes not. that was my point.

Comment: In your last question, I commented, "You can hardly decide not to use atomic if you decide it is too slow, and just hope that you don't have any races!" That opinion just stands.

Comment: What makes you think your compiler won't be able to optimise `x = atm` into a simple `MOV`?

Comment: Are you sure the overhead you're trying to avoid actually matters?  You'll often hear that premature optimization is something to avoid - I hear it often enough that I don't like to invoke the phrase anymore. But in the case of race conditions it's true by at least an order of magnitude more than usual, since any bugs that result from faulty optimizations will be very hard to repro and find the root cause for.  Very hard.  So first make sure that the optimization really matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't get rid of the atomicity property. But you might be able to reduce some of the overhead involved in the use of atomic variables by relaxing the memory ordering guarantees.

```
std::atomic<int> a;

int value = a.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
if(value == 0) {
    // blah!
}
```

I wouldn't recommend doing this however, and I echo all the comments urging you to avoid this. Are you sure that you're paying a high enough cost for the atomic operations that doing this hack and potentially introducing threading bugs is worth it?

Comment: Thanks Martinho, but now I've realized that I don't need an atomic variable at all. The situation is such that a variable x is shared by only two threads, say T1 and T2. First T2 waits for value in x to reach a certain value in a while loop. The value in x is actually set by T1. When this is done, T2 writes 0 to it. T1 waits for T2 to write 0 before it proceed setting value of x again. Do you think this requires atomic operation at all? I think atomic operation is only required when two or more threads in different cores are trying to set a variable at the same time, creating race condition!

Comment: @Metallic: Of course you need some form of synchronization! The situation you described calls for an atomic variable with the *default* memory order, which has all the atomicity and visibility guarantees you need. Also, my answer was not entirely correct.

Answer (score 2):

On most platforms reading an int (especially an aligned one, which a stack variable will be) will be atomic anyway so just assigning it to an int will be a simple assignment anyway.

If the variable isn't accessible atomically as outlined above then you still need to just assign it across to guarantee its not half-written ..

ie Just use the atomic<> variable. Its fine and much safer.

Comment: when you are checking for 0 or nonzero, I think its safe to access it nonatomically.

Comment: @Metallic: What if core 0 updates the value to be nonzero but doesn't flush it to RAM, and core 1 tries to do a check on the value? Multicore machines are allowed to do this without synchronization primitives.

Comment: "accessing an int [...] will be atomic anyway" is true _for all reads and writes_ (...of non-cacheline-crossing, aligned, machineword-or-smaller variables), but __not__ for read-modify-write operations such as increment, decrement, xor, or and.

Comment: @Damon: Thats what i meant will re-word my answer

Comment: @Metallic: **No**. Like I've been trying to say on the question comments, the checks have *nothing to do with thread-safety*. Forget you think it's true. If the variable might be touched by other threads, it needs to be thread-safe, end of story. Checking for zero is completely unrelated.

Comment: @GMan: check my answer in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552172/thread-synchronisation-101 specifically check the part in italics.

Comment: @Damon: Your statement is true -- for Intel compatible x86 systems. Not every system implements automatic hardware cache coherency.

Comment: @Goz: Fair, but I was thinking about other hardware models too. I'll revoke my statement but replace with the much stronger: we ought not code for specific platforms, when the language supplies standard functionality.

Comment: @Gman: Totally thats why i suggest that you'd be best off just using the atomic<> variable directly ;)

Comment: @ZanLynx: It's not even true for x86.  What's true is that a single aligned load or store *instruction* is atomic.  But it doesn't follow, at the level of C++, that `int x; if (x == 0) ...` is atomic, because the compiler is free to read from `x` using something *other* than a single aligned load instruction.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that will work since the value fed to the cast will still have to be obtained from the atomic.  I looked through the [std::atomic< int > specialization declaration](http://www.stdthread.co.uk/doc/headers/atomic/atomic/specializations.html) but as far as I can tell from that, and from their declaration of the base class std::atomic, there is no way to access the underlying variable.

There are macro declarations there that should be able to tell you whether a lock is used at all for your platform, although I'm not sure if these are standard or extension methods. Worst case, you could just evaluate the macro `ATOMIC_INT_LOCK_FREE` and see if it exists. (note: `atomic<int>` handles other things as well, such as ensuring the memory is on proper boundaries, etc.), although it won't matter much for your code; it either will or will not be and there doesn't seem to be a *defined* way to get at the int.

It's also possible you could just play around with it and look at an atomic by setting it to a known value and then inspecting it with a debugger or by taking its address and printing it out. You could play around like that for a bit and probably figure out a way to do some sort of (non-portable, non-standard) pointer manipulation to get a pointer to the value, then store that outside wherever you want to do your non-atomic check.

Hope you find what you need!