# Non atomic operation on atomic variables

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic

Suppose I have this code:

```
std::atomic<int> a1;
std::atomic<int> a2;
std::atomic<int> a3;

std::atomic_store(&a1, 1);
std::atomic_store(&a2, 1);
std::atomic_store(&a3, 2);

int a2Value = std::atomic_load_explicit(&a2, std::memory_order_relaxed);
int a3Value = std::atomic_load_explicit(&a3, std::memory_order_relaxed);

std::atomic_compare_exchange_strong_explicit(
    &a1, 
    &a2Value, 
    a3Value, 
    std::memory_order_relaxed, 
    std::memory_order_relaxed);
```

Can I replace that with the following to avoid two atomic reads (is it safe?):

```
a2Value = static_cast<int>(a2);
a3Value = static_cast<int>(a3);

std::atomic_compare_exchange_strong_explicit(
    &a1, 
    &a2Value, 
    a3Value, 
    std::memory_order_relaxed, 
    std::memory_order_relaxed);
```

Also can I use something like this code to write an atomic variable without it being an atomic write?

```
*reinterpret_cast<int*>(&a2) = 5;
```

Comment: While this will likely work, it technically takes you into undefined behavior land, and is terrible practice.  It is definitely NOT safe from a multi-threading perspective and further using `std::memory_order_relaxed` already grossly reduces the overhead of atomic access.
Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234270/accessing-atomicint-of-c0x-as-non-atomic

Comment: Why are you using atomics if you don't want to use atomics? (And no, that's not safe.)

Comment: Duplicate of the link @SamCristall posted. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234270/accessing-atomicint-of-c0x-as-non-atomic

Comment: Underspecified problem. Why do you use atomics? Are you sure all these object must be atomic? Why? Do they need to be atomic some or all of the time? Do you understand what an "atomic" is?

Comment: You almost can't ever use `reinterpret_cast` in well defined code (probably not even when the std convince ppl you can); if you could, would would destroy the object that was there (the atomic). There is very serious in C++ that you can't reinterpret the bytes not even in these cases that should work (also, atomic of these basic scalar types shouldn't have been allowed to not be lock free).

Comment: @curiousguy All the points that you mentioned are correct. This is an old question that dates back to 2013 when I didn't have a good view of these concepts. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: @MRB I didn't notice how old it was but it's still interesting to consider which types have compatible memory layouts and could be used interchangeably.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, you can't.

If you have a platform where reads of aligned integers are always atomic, then you haven't avoided any atomic operations. If you have a platform where reads of aligned integers aren't always atomic, then the code is obviously unsafe.

Answer (score 1):

It would be great to be able to use atomic and non atomic types interchangeably when atomicity is or isn't needed. However nothing in the C++ model allow it and lots of things go against it.

But the memory model is unsound in the first place (as in: it doesn't define the behavior of anything, it's senseless) so it should be rebuild from scratch and then what you propose should be considered.