# Non-atomic access to atomic through a union

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic

I would like to manipulate the same memory location both atomically and non-atomically.

Let's suppose that I'm working with a simple type, like an `int`, and in particular that `std::atomic<T>::is_lock_free()` returns `true`, and that `sizeof(T) == sizeof(std::atomic<T>)`.

I thought that a `reinterpret_cast` should work:

```
std::atomic<int> x;
int& xx = reinterpret_cast<int&>(x);
```

But [N4013](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4013.html) explains that this may confuse type-based alias analysis in the compiler and therefore is not reliable.

My question is: what about a `union`? If I create the following:

```
union AtomicInt
{
    int nonatomic;
    std::atomic<int> atomic;
};

AtomicInt x;
x.nonatomic = 5;
x.atomic.compare_exchange_weak(...);
```

Will this work as intended? Can I manipulate the same memory atomically and non-atomically?

---

To preempt suggestions about using `load(std::memory_order_relaxed)` in lieu of non-atomic operations,
I've tried the suggestion in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7234782/44738) to a related question, but it slowed my code down by 50%.

Comment: What makes you think `std::atomic<int>` is internally identical to an `int`?

Comment: If it's lock-free and has the same size, I have trouble imagining it being different.

Comment: Me too, but I've been wrong about such things.  I'd venture to say the best results you'll get are that it will appear to work fine - until it doesn't.  You may never get a failure or even notice it.  Accessing the value stored is going to be done in completely different manners.  Changes made via the `int` might not be visible to threads running on another CPU, for example. Look at the instructions your compiler emits and see if looks like it should work. At best, I'd say "working" would be platform-dependent UB.  But you just might need to do that for performance reasons.

Comment: This sounds like hacking around a problem instead of solving the actual problem. If you are doing load/modify/store operations on an atomic so much that performance is a concern, then its time to start thinking about holding that data more locally. Would it be possible to load to a nonatomic type once, modify many times, then store to the atomic once? (Not knowing your usage pattern, it's hard to make any other suggestions.)

Comment: (cont)  If you're using the `int` access path just to read the value, for example, and you don't care that you might have a somewhat "old" value, it could be just fine.  But I'd test the heck out of it.

Comment: I have separate stages of my program. During the first, the execution is serial. There is literally one thread, and I'd like it to access memory non-atomically. During the second stage, the execution is parallel. There are multiple threads, and they coordinate using compare-and-swaps. In all cases, there is one complicated data structure that the code is modifying. If I had a better way to organize it, I would, but I think mine is a legitimate problem (and it's come up in other questions).

Comment: There is also a larger philosophical point. The processor lets you access the same memory atomically and non-atomically. The separation is on the level of operations. C++ somehow forces you to decide on this division on the level of data. That's both inefficient and departs from how the hardware does it. I'm trying to find a "stable" fix.

Comment: What you wrote is UB.

Comment: @lorro, why? The paper I linked to explains why the `reinterpret_cast` is problematic. Why is the `union` undefined behavior?

Comment: @foxcub: writing to one member of an union and reading another is UB. The only exception is some legacy from C: aggregate structs in a union that have the same first C integer member. This was specifically asked for lexers.

Comment: The exception is not too far from what we have. `std::atomic<int>` is surely just a struct wrapping an `int` with some special behavior in the operations. I guess I could wrap the non-atomic `int` in a struct.

Answer (score -1):

Lock-free atomic primitives are for highly congested concurrency. If there's high congestion, and you start using your atomic variables as non-atomic, you'll definitely introduce bugs, **even** if on that particular architecture `int` and `atomic<int>` has the same layout.

If you have low congestion but require particular ordering in some cases, you should use locks.

Comment: I would never start using my variables as non-atomic during parallel execution. I want to use them as non-atomic during the serial execution that precedes the atomic execution.

Comment: Then why don't just use another (non atomic) variable before it, and assign it to an atomic later?

Comment: I don't want the copying (and the memory) overhead.